Is it legal to improve or change firmware-b43-installer Ubuntu package for personal use on my devices?
The situation:
I enhanced the firmware-b43-installer Ubuntu package to include b43-fwcutter Ubuntu package, and b43 wifi driver. befor this modification, the firmware-b43-installer package requires an Internet connection to download the b43 wifi diver file in a compressed form from its source. It also requires a package to unzip this compressed file and b43-fwcutter package to install the firmware.
The firmware license:
In the source of downloading the driver (http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/), I don't find the license in any version on this page except in the file http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.10.56.51.tar.bz2, and this is a screenshot of the license file:

This text appeared in all files included in the /config directory in all versions:

Also, I asked b43-fwcutter package on launchpad.net/ubuntu  what is the license for using this broadcom-wl-6.30.163.46.wl_apsta.o file?  I am waiting for their answer.
The question:
Is it legal to improve or change firmware-b43-installer Ubuntu package for personal use on my devices?

formal answer: you need to ask a copyright lawyer. In my country it is illegal to provide legal advice as a non-lawyer. question: why not provide a bugfix to the original package? seems more ideal for all others users of this package.

I’m voting to close this question because this is not possible to answer without a legal analysis of the firmware; the license of the package itself is permissive but we don't know anything about the firmware license.

@TalaatEtman ok. It still makes no difference until you analyse the firmware license.

I wonder what the source of the license text you have added to the question as being the firmware license is. I cannot find any such license text in the tarballs that this package downloads. But I do see a similar copyright notice in this PDF. Did you just add the license of some random Broadcom product as the license of this firmware?

Hmm, seems I found it: https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/blob/master/release/src-rt/wl/config/wl.mk It even has the # comment characters the post originally had for the license. That's not the license of the firmware, those are just helper files for another system to make use of the firmware.

In fact, that repo includes the prebuilt binary wl firmware elsewhere, while leaving this statement on their website: "Note that some components are proprietary to various entities (Asus, Broadcom, [...]).  For these, the pre-compiled binary blobs are included in the repository [...] Copyrights belong to their respective owners." The whole repo seems to be illegal IMO, since they claim the repo is GPL-licensed without making any exceptions for these firmware files.

Reopen voters: please be more careful when reviewing such posts! This post is claiming a pretty liberal license applies to an infamously proprietary firmware blob.

The b43 driver I used which is mentioned in this Ubuntu help page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx
I use the same method and the same files from the same sources, and firmware-b43-installer uses the same files and sources.

The b43 driver is already part of the kernel, you don't even need to download that. What you're downloading is the firmware, and that is not permissively licensed.

@TalaatEtman yes, please do see the output: "from a proprietary Broadcom 43xx device driver file.

I don't have to ask anyone anything, since I am not the one using it: you are. It's your responsibility to know what the licenses of software you're using are. At any rate, you can't claim some random license applies to software to which the license is unclear. The default is all rights reserved, not all rights waived.

As far as the firmware-b43-installer package itself is concerned, it's easy to find the answer out to this. Download the source package with apt source firmware-b43-installer, change to the source package directory that this command produces (at the time of this writing this is b43-fwcutter-019 with the Ubuntu 24.04 repos), then cat debian/copyright to look at the copyright and licensing info of the package. All official Debian and Ubuntu packages are required to list their copyright and licensing info in this file, and thus you can use it to quickly look up info about these kinds of things. At least with the copy of firmware-b43-installer I downloaded, the entire package is listed as being under the BSD-2-Clause license (with the exception of some md5-related files which are listed as being public domain). The full text of this license is as follows:

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.

Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.


THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS “AS IS” AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

At least with my non-lawyer interpretation of the license, modifying the package itself is probably just fine.
Where things get stickier is the license for your WiFi driver. Depending on the terms of the driver itself, this may be perfectly fine, or it could be a license violation. You will have to read the license agreement for that driver to find out whether or not integrating it into a package in this way for personal use is allowable or not.

If you are doing this on your home computer, for your personal use, really nobody would care if this is legal or not. Nobody is going to enter your home and search your computer to check if you modified that package, or going to sue you for this.
If you plan to use this computer for business purposes, within a company, ask your lawyer. Check the license of that particular package; the license may explicitly allow modifications. Even if it doesn't, your country's copyright law may allow it. For example, in my country copyright law explicitly allows modifying any program that you have a legal right to use, if this is "necessary for using the program according to its purpose", which also explicitly includes fixing bugs. Of course your case may be different.
